# PHP/SQL Logic for a Like/Dislike Feature

Tags: php, sql

I'm looking to code a [ like | dislike ] feature utilizing PHP/SQL in the best and most efficient way possible.

I currently have two tables: `users` & `content`

- How should I store a user's likes and dislikes?
- How should I store the number of likes a particular content item has?

I'm looking for the best logic possible so I'm not overloading my site with inefficient queries.

Comment: Please be more specific. Generally using a single table to store answers would be best, but it depends on specific circumstances.

Comment: Each option has different advantages and disadvantages (though a likes and dislikes table should be just one table, I would think).  If you keep it in the table, COUNT clauses become unnecessary meaning the selecting is much quicker.  However, updating will start causing locking issues if you ever have 10 people trying to like something at a time.  If you have a separate table, COUNT queries will be a bit slower than reading a column, but the locking won't be *as* bad when adding new entries (note that I'm making a few assumptions here).  And you could always do a hybrid version.

Comment: This is really vague.  Is this going into a bigger program/project or are you just going to collect likes and dislikes?

Comment: Pardon the vagueness of the question, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sample table

```
posts
----
id
content
user


users
----
id
username

user_likes
----
id
user
post_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new table `user_likes` and maybe a table `likes_details` linked together by foreign keys to keep user "likes," and information about this ones (as date, ip, or anything else), look into db `normalization`.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your database structure normalized. That means you

- chop attributes as far as possible. e.g.: don't create a field
  "address" but three fields "street" "postcode" "housenumber" instead.
- only put coherent attributes together into a table. e.g: a table "person" could contains of fields like "person_id", "height", "weight" or "eye_color" but not fields like "address". create a second table instead which is called "person_addresses" which contains fields like "person_id", "street", "postcode", "housenumber".

So the efficient way for your case is to create two tables. first one "user" with the field "user_id" and second one "likes_dislikes" with the fields "user_id", "likes" and "dislikes".

Take a look at this wiki entry to learn more about database normalization:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization